# Why Fock representation holds only in a free quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, interactions

With a quantum system with $N$ degrees of freedom, all the representations are unitarily equivalent to Fock representation. However, if the number of degrees of freedom goes to infinity, there are infinite inequivalent representations, and only if the dynamics is "free", then the represetation is Fock. This is according to several textbooks (like "Symmetry breaking" by Strocchi and "Local quantum physics" by Haag). However, I am missing the reason why, if the Hamiltonian is "free", then the representation is Fock.
Moreover, I have only seen this logic in relativistic quantum field theory. How about with non-relativistic quantum field theory? In this case, for "free" theory is meant non-interacting or (non-interacting + harmonic potential)?

Comment: If you've read Haag, you should understand why - after all, this is Haag's theorem. Can you be more specific what you don't understand about the proof of Haag's theorem?

Comment: In "Local quantum physics" Hagg's Theorem is barely touched (unless I missed it) and, for what it says, it concerns the existence of interaction picture in relativistic quantum field theory